# Calling a method of a class within a class (non-inherited separate classes)

Tags: class, python-3.x

So I have a GameLogic class in a game I am making that contains all relevant Game Classes within it:

```
class GameLogic()
    def __init(self):
        self.Player = Player()
        self.Business = Business()

        self.EventLog = []

    def logEvent(self, event, effect, business):
        self.EventLog.append('some stuff')
```

Now the Gamelogic class has a method that logs events to it's event log. The event log is printed each turn, then wiped.

Is there a way to call `logEvent()` from within Business for example, so that gameLogic may recieve events from the various subclasses that have things happen to them?

Comment: You could pass your `GameLogic` instance to the `Business` initialiser so it has a handle on which to call `GameLogic` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to give a reference to `GameLogic` to each class. This is often called a "controller", as it controls access to other classes.

```
class GameLogic():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Player = Player(self)
        self.Business = Business(self)
    ...

class Player(...):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
```

Later, within your classes you can call logEvent via the `controller` attribute:

```
self.controller.logEvent(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bryan. I've been thinking about this one way too long now, you are awesome!